# Bold an array in PHP code using PHPExcel

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

How can I make an array bold in my PHP code and save it in the excel file using PHPExcel class? I would like to also know how to make the background in the saved file have colors:

Example of what I want:

[image]

**My Current Code:**

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['send'])) { ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php } else {
    require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php';
    $filename = 'file.xlsx';
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("cant connect!");
    mysql_select_db("test") or die ("cant find database!");

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM score");
    if(isset($_POST['send'])){

        $headings = array(
            'ID', 
            'NAME',
            'SCORE 1',
            'SCORE 2',
            'OTHER QUALITIES',
            'INTERVIEW',
            'TOTAL',
            'AIC',
            'BATCHCODE',
        );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
             ->getStyle('A1:I5')
             ->getAlignment()
             ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($headings, null, 'A1');
        $row = 2;
        while( $rows = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($rows, null, 'A' . $row);
            $row++;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$title.'.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
if (!isset($_POST['send'])) { ?>

    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" >
    <input name="title" type="text" id="title" value="title" />
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send to excel" id="send" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php }
```

Comment: I'm really beginning to wonder why I bother writing documentation, or providing Example code with PHPExcel

Comment: @Mark Baker r u the creator of PHPexcel? +_+ if 'yes' AWESOME :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting if from an array is probably the easiest way:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:I1')->applyFromArray(
            array(
                'font' => array(
                    'bold' => true
                ),
                'alignment' => array(
                    'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
                ),
                'borders' => array(
                    'top' => array(
                        'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
                    )
                ),
                'fill' => array(
                    'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR,
                    'rotation' => 90,
                    'startcolor' => array(
                        'argb' => 'FFA0A0A0'
                    ),
                    'endcolor' => array(
                        'argb' => 'FFFFFFFF'
                    )
                )
            )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the **cell style** getting the font.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle("$cell:$cell")
            ->getFont()
             ->setBold(true);
```

or use this function for the background color

```
function cellColor($cells, $bgcolor, $color){
    global $objPHPExcel;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cells)->getFill()
    ->applyFromArray(array('type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
    'startcolor' => array('rgb' => $bgcolor),
    'endcolor' => array('rgb' => $color)
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try it!**

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['send'])) { ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php } else {
    require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php';
    $filename = 'file.xlsx';
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("cant connect!");
    mysql_select_db("test") or die ("cant find database!");

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM score");
    if(isset($_POST['send'])){

        $headings = array(
            'ID', 
            'NAME',
            'SCORE 1',
            'SCORE 2',
            'OTHER QUALITIES',
            'INTERVIEW',
            'TOTAL',
            'AIC',
            'BATCHCODE',
        );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:I5')->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:I5')->applyFromArray(array('fill' => array('type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID, 'color' => array('rgb' => 'CCCCCC') ), ) );
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setAutoSize(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
             ->getStyle('A1:I5')
             ->getAlignment()
             ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($headings, null, 'A1');
        $row = 2;
        while( $rows = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($rows, null, 'A' . $row);
            $row++;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$title.'.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
if (!isset($_POST['send'])) { ?>

    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" >
    <input name="title" type="text" id="title" value="title" />
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send to excel" id="send" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php }
```